# MongoDB slice - remove last n elements from nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Supposing I have the following array:

```
{
   data: [1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
}
```

if I want to select all the elements, except the last 3, I can use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047651/12832931)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "data": {
        "$slice": [ 
          "$data",
          0,
          {
            $subtract: [ { $size: "$data" }, 3 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I can get the desired output:

```
[1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0]
```

How can I do the same thing for concatenated/nested arrays like:

```
 {
       data: [[1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 1], [1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3]]
 }
```

In order to select all the elements, except the last 3 (of each array)?

Expected output:

```
        {
           data: [[1, 0, 4, 0], [1, 0, 4, 0]]
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to iterate over array's & do the same :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: {
            "$slice": [
              "$$this",
              0,
              {
                $subtract: [
                  {
                    $size: "$$this"
                  },
                  3
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p0H7JCce--a)

Comment: Thank you very much